# Total time in python's line profiler is strange

Tags: python, sorting, profiling

This is my insertion.py:

```
import random

#@profile
def insertion_sort(l):
    for j in range(1, len(l)):
        k = l[j]
        i = j - 1
        while i >= 0 and l[i] > k:
            l[i + 1] = l[i]
            i -= 1
        l[i + 1] = k


if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = range(5000)
    random.shuffle(l)
    insertion_sort(l)
```

When I run `time python insertion.py`, I get:

```
real    0m0.823s
user    0m0.818s
sys     0m0.004s
```

But when I uncomment the profile decorator and run: `kernprof -l -v insertion.py`, I get:

```
Wrote profile results to insertion.py.lprof
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 7.25971 s
File: insertion.py
Function: insertion_sort at line 4

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
 4                                           @profile
 5                                           def insertion_sort(l):
 6      5000         2110      0.4      0.0      for j in range(1, len(l)):
 7      4999         1929      0.4      0.0          k = l[j]
 8      4999         1719      0.3      0.0          i = j - 1
 9   6211255      2695158      0.4     37.1          while i >= 0 and l[i] > k:
10   6206256      2396675      0.4     33.0              l[i + 1] = l[i] 
11   6206256      2160158      0.3     29.8              i -= 1
12      4999         1959      0.4      0.0          l[i + 1] = k
```

My question is why total time of line profiler is much greater than the system time? I thought "Total time" of line profiler was describing how much time the function decorated with @profile was running. In my head, the output from `time` should be greater or at least close to line profiler. Am I interpreting the results wrong? Is line profiler adding its own time to "Total time"?

Comment: That is odd. According to the [line_profiler docs](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler/blob/master/README.rst) it should only add a small amount of its own time to that of the lines it's timing, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My results show that the [`ContextualProfile`](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler/blob/74b83c7d15c762cbed7ebdf3794f6b07013a57bc/kernprof.py#L202) adds almost no overhead in this case, but the [`LineProfiler`](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler/blob/74b83c7d15c762cbed7ebdf3794f6b07013a57bc/kernprof.py#L199) adds a very large amount of overhead.

This is not entirely surprising, because `LineProfiler` executes [a bunch of code](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler/blob/8f44d6cf640ce2754af07a4c16e30b9d7e1582de/_line_profiler.pyx#L187) for [every line](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler/blob/8f44d6cf640ce2754af07a4c16e30b9d7e1582de/_line_profiler.pyx#L158). So, the lines that were previously a simple assignment or a simple comparison now include several comparisons, function calls and data structures.

In my results, the `LineProfiler` overhead can be estimated as between 527 and 615 nanoseconds per line, calculated by dividing the total time (11.2287s) by the number of hits (5000 + 4999 + 4999 + 6081512 + 6076513 + 6076513 + 4999 = 18254535 ≅ 18M), and then subtracting the total time of the other profiler divided by the same number of hits. Again, this is just a rough estimation of the overhead.

---

The complete output is listed below:

```
$ time python2 insertion.py

real    0m1.561s
user    0m1.548s
sys     0m0.012s

$ sed -i 's/^#@profile$/@profile/' insertion.py
$ kernprof -b -v insertion.py
Wrote profile results to insertion.py.prof
         5 function calls in 1.619 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    1.619    1.619    1.619    1.619 insertion.py:5(insertion_sort)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 kernprof.py:63(disable_by_count)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}

$ kernprof -b -l -v insertion.py
Wrote profile results to insertion.py.lprof
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 11.2287 s
File: insertion.py
Function: insertion_sort at line 5

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     5                                           @profile
     6                                           def insertion_sort(l):
     7      5000         2819      0.6      0.0      for j in range(1, len(l)):
     8      4999         2870      0.6      0.0          k = l[j]
     9      4999         2792      0.6      0.0          i = j - 1
    10   6081512      3871421      0.6     34.5          while i >= 0 and l[i] > k:
    11   6076513      4014703      0.7     35.8              l[i + 1] = l[i]
    12   6076513      3330633      0.5     29.7              i -= 1
    13      4999         3425      0.7      0.0          l[i + 1] = k
```

Comment: It actually solves my doubt. Using the -b option convinced me. Thank you!